# Can not run protractor with gulp (ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: gulp, protractor

I could run it  before. But now i cant. It is in a project. My friend who has this project from git latst repository (that is also how i imported) can run protractor under gateway with gulp protractor qa. But for me it gives errors

```
vegan@vegan:~/xxx-yyyy/gateway$ gulp protractor qa
[16:04:08] Using gulpfile ~/xxx-yyyy/gateway/gulpfile.js
[16:04:08] Starting 'protractor'...
[16:04:08] Starting 'qa'...
[16:04:08] Finished 'qa' after 67 μs
Using ChromeDriver directly...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver

/home/vegan/xxx-yyyy/gateway/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:174
      callback(new Error(message));
               ^
Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:40886
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/vegan/xxx-yyyy/gateway/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:174:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:306:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1265:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (/home/vegan/xxx-yyyy/gateway/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:157:22)
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (/home/vegan/xxx-yyyy/gateway/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:131:30)
    at new Driver (/home/vegan/xxx-yyyy/gateway/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:810:36)
    at [object Object].DirectDriverProvider.getNewDriver (/home/vegan/xxx-yyyy/gateway/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/direct.js:68:16)
    at [object Object].Runner.createBrowser (/home/vegan/xxx-yyyy/gateway/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:186:37)
    at /home/vegan/xxx-yyyy/gateway/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:276:21
    at _fulfilled (/home/vegan/xxx-yyyy/gateway/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/vegan/xxx-yyyy/gateway/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/vegan/xxx-yyyy/gateway/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
    at /home/vegan/xxx-yyyy/gateway/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:525:49
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
[16:04:10] gulp-notify: [JHipster Gulp Build] Error: protractor exited with code 1
[16:04:10] Finished 'protractor' after 2.41 s
[16:04:10] E2E Tests failed
```

I did not touch any of conf files of protractor. They are default.

that is in package json

```
 },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^4.3"
  },
```

this is the error line for 174

```
  request.on('error', function(e) {
    if (e.code === 'ECONNRESET') {
      setTimeout(function() {
        sendRequest(options, callback, opt_data, opt_proxy);
      }, 15);
    } else {
      var message = e.message;
      if (e.code) {
        message = e.code + ' ' + message;
      }
      callback(new Error(message));
    }
  });
```

this is in packagejson in selenumwebdriver

```
{
  "_args": [
    [
      "selenium-webdriver@https://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver/-/selenium-webdriver-2.48.2.tgz",
      "/home/vegan/xxx-yyyy/gateway"
    ]
  ],
  "_from": "selenium-webdriver@2.48.2",
  "_id": "selenium-webdriver@2.48.2",
  "_inCache": true,
  "_location": "/selenium-webdriver",
  "_phantomChildren": {
    "bufferutil": "1.2.1",
    "options": "0.0.6",
    "ultron": "1.0.2",
    "utf-8-validate": "1.2.2",
    "xmlbuilder": "4.2.1"
  },
  "_requested": {
    "name": "selenium-webdriver",
    "raw": "selenium-webdriver@https://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver/-/selenium-webdriver-2.48.2.tgz",
    "rawSpec": "https://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver/-/selenium-webdriver-2.48.2.tgz",
    "scope": null,
    "spec": "https://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver/-/selenium-webdriver-2.48.2.tgz",
    "type": "remote"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "/gulp-protractor/protractor",
    "/protractor"
  ],
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver/-/selenium-webdriver-2.48.2.tgz",
  "_shasum": "b26a4631430d0a9f36284ee0cfe09676e8f348ca",
  "_shrinkwrap": null,
  "_spec": "selenium-webdriver@https://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver/-/selenium-webdriver-2.48.2.tgz",
  "_where": "/home/vegan/xx-yyyy/gateway",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "adm-zip": "0.4.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.2.8",
    "tmp": "0.0.24",
    "ws": "^0.8.0",
    "xml2js": "0.4.4"
  },
  "description": "The official WebDriver JavaScript bindings from the Selenium project",
  "devDependencies": {
    "express": "^4.11.2",
    "mocha": ">= 1.21.x",
    "multer": "^0.1.7",
    "promises-aplus-tests": "^2.1.0",
    "serve-index": "^1.6.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.12.x"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium",
  "keywords": [
    "automation",
    "selenium",
    "testing",
    "webdriver",
    "webdriverjs"
  ],
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "main": "./index",
  "name": "selenium-webdriver",
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "readme": "# selenium-webdriver\n\nSelenium is a browser automation library. Most often used for testing\nweb-applications, Selenium may be used for any task that requires automating\ninteraction with the browser.\n\n## Installation\n\nSelenium supports Node `0.12.x` and `4.x`. Users on Node `0.12.x` must run with\nthe --harmony flag. Selenium may be installed via npm with\n\n    npm install selenium-webdriver\n\nOut of the box, Selenium includes everything you need to work with Firefox. You\nwill need to download additional components to work with the other major\nbrowsers. The drivers for Chrome, IE, PhantomJS, and Opera are all standalone\nexecutables that should be placed on your\n[PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29). The SafariDriver\nbrowser extension should be installed in your browser before using Selenium; we\nrecommend disabling the extension when using the browser without Selenium or\ninstalling the extension in a profile only used for testing.\n\n| Browser           | Component                          |\n| ----------------- | ---------------------------------- |\n| Chrome            | [chromedriver(.exe)][chrome]       |\n| Internet Explorer | [IEDriverServer.exe][release]      |\n| PhantomJS         | [phantomjs(.exe)][phantomjs]       |\n| Opera             | [operadriver(.exe)][opera]         |\n| Safari            | [SafariDriver.safariextz][release] |\n\n## Usage\n\nThe sample below and others are included in the `example` directory. You may\nalso find the tests for selenium-webdriver informative.\n\n    var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),\n        By = require('selenium-webdriver').By,\n        until = require('selenium-webdriver').until;\n\n    var driver = new webdriver.Builder()\n        .forBrowser('firefox')\n        .build();\n\n    driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');\n    driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');\n    driver.findElement(By.name('btnG')).click();\n    driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);\n    driver.quit();\n\n### Using the Builder API\n\nThe `Builder` class is your one-stop shop for configuring new WebDriver\ninstances. Rather than clutter your code with branches for the various browsers,\nthe builder lets you set all options in one flow. When you call\n`Builder#build()`, all options irrelevant to the selected browser are dropped:\n\n    var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),\n        chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome'),\n        firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');\n\n    var driver = new webdriver.Builder()\n        .forBrowser('firefox')\n        .setChromeOptions(/* ... */)\n        .setFirefoxOptions(/* ... */)\n        .build();\n\nWhy would you want to configure options irrelevant to the target browser? The\n`Builder`'s API defines your _default_ configuration. You can change the target\nbrowser at runtime through the `SELENIUM_BROWSER` environment variable. For\nexample, the `example/google_search.js` script is configured to run against\nFirefox. You can run the example against other browsers just by changing the\nruntime environment\n\n    # cd node_modules/selenium-webdriver\n    node example/google_search\n    SELENIUM_BROWSER=chrome node example/google_search\n    SELENIUM_BROWSER=safari node example/google_search\n\n### The Standalone Selenium Server\n\nThe standalone Selenium Server acts as a proxy between your script and the\nbrowser-specific drivers. The server may be used when running locally, but it's\nnot recommend as it introduces an extra hop for each request and will slow\nthings down. The server is required, however, to use a browser on a remote host\n(most browser drivers, like the IEDriverServer, do not accept remote\nconnections).\n\nTo use the Selenium Server, you will need to install the\n[JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and\ndownload the latest server from [Selenium][release]. Once downloaded, run the\nserver with\n\n    java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar\n\nYou may configure your tests to run against a remote server through the Builder\nAPI:\n\n    var driver = new webdriver.Builder()\n        .forBrowser('firefox')\n        .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')\n        .build();\n\nOr change the Builder's configuration at runtime with the `SELENIUM_REMOTE_URL`\nenvironment variable:\n\n    SELENIUM_REMOTE_URL=\"http://localhost:4444/wd/hub\" node script.js\n\nYou can experiment with these options using the `example/google_search.js`\nscript provided with `selenium-webdriver`.\n\n## Documentation\n\nAPI documentation is included in the `docs` directory and is also available\nonline from the [Selenium project][api]. Addition resources include\n\n- the #selenium channel on freenode IRC\n- the [selenium-users@googlegroups.com][users] list\n- [SeleniumHQ](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/) documentation\n\n## Contributing\n\nContributions are accepted either through [GitHub][gh] pull requests or patches\nvia the [Selenium issue tracker][issues]. You must sign our\n[Contributor License Agreement][cla] before your changes will be accepted.\n\n## Issues\n\nPlease report any issues using the [Selenium issue tracker][issues]. When using\nthe issue tracker\n\n- __Do__ include a detailed description of the problem.\n- __Do__ include a link to a [gist](http://gist.github.com/) with any\n    interesting stack traces/logs (you may also attach these directly to the bug\n    report).\n- __Do__ include a [reduced test case][reduction]. Reporting \"unable to find\n    element on the page\" is _not_ a valid report - there's nothing for us to\n    look into. Expect your bug report to be closed if you do not provide enough\n    information for us to investigate.\n- __Do not__ use the issue tracker to submit basic help requests. All help\n    inquiries should be directed to the [user forum][users] or #selenium IRC\n    channel.\n- __Do not__ post empty \"I see this too\" or \"Any updates?\" comments. These\n    provide no additional information and clutter the log.\n- __Do not__ report regressions on closed bugs as they are not actively\n    monitored for upates (especially bugs that are >6 months old). Please open a\n    new issue and reference the original bug in your report.\n\n## License\n\nLicensed to the Software Freedom Conservancy (SFC) under one\nor more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file\ndistributed with this work for additional information\nregarding copyright ownership.  The SFC licenses this file\nto you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the\n\"License\"); you may not use this file except in compliance\nwith the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at\n\nhttp://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0\n\nUnless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,\nsoftware distributed under the License is distributed on an\n\"AS IS\" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY\nKIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the\nspecific language governing permissions and limitations\nunder the License.\n\n[api]: http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/\n[cla]: http :/ /go o.gl/qC50R\n[chrome]: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html\n[gh]: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/\n[issues]: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues\n[opera]: https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases\n[phantomjs]: http://phantomjs.org/\n[reduction]: http://www.webkit.org/quality/reduction.html\n[release]: http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html\n[users]: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users\n",
  "readmeFilename": "README.md",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --harmony -t 600000 --recursive test"
  },
  "version": "2.48.2"
}
```

those are versions

```
vegan@vegan:~/xx-yyyy/gateway$ node -v
v5.12.0
vegan@vegan:~/xx-yyyy/gateway$ npm -v
3.8.6
```

my friend also has this versions but he can run Also i could until lasst week. I dont know what happened. I deleted node modules, resetted all but did not work.

i dont know what i can give information about.

i also tried this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34758398/6804200

changed configjson to this

```
{
  "webdriverVersions": {
      "seleniumServerJar": './node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.51.0.jar',
      "chromedriver": "2.21",
    "iedriver": "2.51.0"
  }
}
```

but nothng changed.

i did also `npm update`

gulp protractor is

```
gulp.task(
    'protractor', function () {


        configObj['args'] = [];//to be able to add multiple parameters

        if (argv.suite) {
            configObj['args'].push(
                '--suite',
                argv.suite
            );
        }

        return gulp.src([])
            .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
            .pipe(protractor(configObj))
            .on(
                'error', function () {
                        gutil.log('E2E Tests failed');
                        process.exit(1);
                    }
                );
        }
    );
var configObj = {
    configFile: config.test + 'protractor.conf.js'
};
```

protractorconf is

```
var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require("protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter");
var JasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

var prefix = 'src/test/javascript/'.replace(/[^/]+/g, '..');



exports.config = {

    chromeDriver: prefix + 'node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver',
    allScriptsTimeout: 240000,

    suites: {
        register: './e2e/account/register/*.js',
        login: './e2e/account/login/*.js'

    },

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },

    directConnect: true,

    framework: 'jasmine2',

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 240000
    },
    onPrepare: function () {

        var disableNgAnimate = function () {
            angular
                .module('disableNgAnimate', [])
                .run(
                    [
                        '$animate',
                        function ($animate) {
                            $animate.enabled(false);
                        }
                    ]
                );
        };

        var disableCssAnimate = function () {
            angular
                .module('disableCssAnimate', [])
                .run(
                    function () {
                        var style = document.createElement('style');
                        style.type = 'text/css';
                        style.innerHTML = 'body * {' +
                            '-webkit-transition: none !important;' +
                            '-moz-transition: none !important;' +
                            '-o-transition: none !important;' +
                            '-ms-transition: none !important;' +
                            'transition: none !important;' +
                            '}';
                        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
                    }
                );
        };

        browser.addMockModule('disableNgAnimate', disableNgAnimate);
        browser.addMockModule('disableCssAnimate', disableCssAnimate);

        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();


    }
};
```

gulp tasks of qa

```
gulp.task('qa', function () {

    argv.baseUrl = qaurl;

    configObj['args'].push(
        '--baseUrl',
        argv.baseUrl
    );
});
```

i got this when i do npm install

> npm WARN lifecycle gateway@0.0.0~postinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s
>   (wd=%s) gateway@0.0.0 webdriver-manager update
>   /home/vegan/xx-yyy/gateway npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional
>   dependency /chokidar/fsevents: npm WARN notsup Not compatible with
>   your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.17

also i get this

```
vegan@vegan:~/xx-yyy/gateway$ sudo npm install -g protractor
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
/usr/bin/protractor -> /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor
/usr/bin/webdriver-manager -> /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager
/usr/lib
└─┬ protractor@5.0.0 
  └── source-map-support@0.4.11
```

it is a spring boot project. it uses gulp. the project is not needed to be up to run the protractor.

Comment: I don't use `gulp`, but any time I get `ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED` it means I forgot to open `webdriver-manager start`

Comment: But it opens itself. I did not open it ever.

Comment: Can you try changing the port number?

Answer (score 3):

Remove & reinstall npm, gulp, nodejs.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please update the gulp-protractor-qa plugin. Mean while i hope you are using gulp-protractor update that also.
Update gulp-protractor to version 3.0.0 
npm update gulp-protractor & give a try it should work.

Comment: I added to answer. i did npm pdate but did not work. I also put my gulp protractor. i dont undertand gulp qa plugin. it is a task.